# If $\int _0^{x^2}t^2f\left(t\right)dt=\left(x\:+1\right)^2\sin x^2$, then value of $f\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$ is

Tags: integration

Option

a)$\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi \:}}\right)4}{\pi ^2}$

b) $\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi \:}}\right)4}{\pi ^2}$

c) $\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi \:}}\right)1}{\pi ^2}$

d) $\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi \:}}\right)4}{\pi }$

Answer (score 2):

Given equation $$ \int_0^{x^2} t^2 f(t) dt = (x+1)^2 \sin(x^2) $$ On differentiating both sides and by using [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule): $$ 2x^5 f(x^2) = (x+1) ( 2 \sin(x^2) + 2x(x+1) \cos(x^2)) $$ $$ \Rightarrow f(x^2) = \cfrac{(x+1) ( 2 \sin(x^2) + 2x(x+1) \cos(x^2))}{2x^5} $$

On placing $x ^2 = \cfrac{\pi}{2} $ $$f \bigg( \frac{\pi}{2} \bigg) = \cfrac{4}{\pi^2} \bigg(1 + \sqrt{\cfrac{2}{\pi}} \bigg )$$